# Selecting 10 rows randomly in mysql

Tags: mysql, random

How can i get 10 rows randomly from a table with at least 1 million registers? I read about order by random() but many saids it is so slow. which algorithm can i use in this case?

Answer (score 3):

It's true that `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT n` is time-consuming. But it does give a pretty good pseudorandom selection of `n` distinct rows.

You can try this instead. It will still have to scan your table, but it won't have to sort.  This doesn't guarantee exactly ten rows; it may yield more or fewer.

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
          SELECT a.*
            FROM mytable a
            JOIN (select COUNT(*) rowcnt, 10 samplecnt from mytable) c
           WHERE RAND() <= (CAST(samplecnt AS DOUBLE) )/ CAST(rowcnt AS DOUBLE)
       ) sample
 ORDER BY rand()
```

It works by using a pseudorandom number to choose whether or not to include each row of your table in the result set.

On a test table I have with 750K rows, the `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10` approach was three times slower than the `WHERE RAND() <=...` approach.

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I added your technique as the 8th in my blog (above).  In the process, I doubled the speed by replacing the `COUNT(*)` with a fetch of `TABLE_ROWS` from `information_schema`.  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/random#case_full_scan_but_less_to_process